# Can nHibernate be used to access google cloud SQL server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nhibernate, google-cloud-sql

We are porting our legacy application in nHibernate to Google cloud .
Can nHibernate be used to access Google coud SQL server in resilient manner?

There are separate NuGet package to access Google cloud Spanner from nHibernate. But I am not finding anything to access Google Cloud Sql server using nHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about configuration. You need :

- to specify the google clound connexion string in the NHibernate configuration.
- the SqlServer driver nuget package
  Everithing should works fine.